# Randomly printing out size of int, no idea why

Tags: c++, int

For some reason this code is printing out the size of an int after getting multiple inputs. I am a beginner in c++ and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out and help me understand why this is happening. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int calculateVowelIndex(std::string input)
{
float numVowel = 0, numCon = 0;
int vowelIndex;

std::vector<char> vowels{ 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y' };

std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), ::tolower);

for (int x = 0; x < input.length(); ++x)
{
    if (std::find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), input[x]) != vowels.end())
        ++numVowel;

    else
        ++numCon;
}

vowelIndex = numVowel / (numVowel + numCon) * 100;

return vowelIndex;
}

int main()
{
int n;
std::string input;
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::vector <unsigned int> vowelIndexes;
std::cin >> n;

for (int x = 0; x < n; ++x)
{
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    words.push_back(input);
    vowelIndexes.push_back(calculateVowelIndex(input));
}

for (int x = 0; x < words.size(); ++x)
{
    std::cout << vowelIndexes.at(x) << " " << words.at(x) << std::endl;
}

std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: not really clear what you mean with "printing out the size of an int", could you provide an example output (together with corresponding input)

Comment: Why does `calculateVowelIndex` return `int`, when the result is pushed into a `std::vector<unsigned int>`?

Comment: if I input 3, and then 2 words, after the second word it prints out the size of an int (2,147,483,647) and doesn't let me input the 3rd word.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that @InternetAussie

Comment: The number 2,147,483,647 (= 2^31 − 1) is the maximum value of `int` rather than its size which is 32 bits (4 bytes). Please provide a sample input, nothing is printed in my try: https://ideone.com/ZpBEQt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that this happens because when you type in the input, there ends up being an extra newline that then gets gobbled by the first iteration of `std::getline`. Once you've typed in the input for the number of words, `std::cin`'s buffer could look like this:

```
"3\n"
```

The `std::cin >> n;` parse the integer and stops when it reaches the newline, leaving this in `std::cin`:

```
"\n"
```

The first call then to `std::getline` reads in all the characters (which there are none here) until it reaches a newline (the `'\n'`), which it then reads and discards, leaving nothing in `std::cin`. So a blank line is read in and passed to the function on the first iteration.

This leaves two more iterations of the loop. The next two calls to `std::getline` have no input to read from `std::cin`, so it prompts you for more, and the loop processes it accordingly.

> if I input 3, and then 2 words, after the second word it prints out the size of an int (2,147,483,647) and doesn't let me input the 3rd word.

This is why that happens: a forgotten newline is read in and taken as the end of an empty line.

To remedy this, we must read any left over characters in the line and discard them before reading any more lines. This can be done with the [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) method on `std::cin`, like so:

```
// ...
std::cin >> n;

// skip the rest of the line
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

for (int x = 0; x < n; ++x)
// ...
```

`std::numeric_limits` is in `<limits>`. This reads and discards every character until it encounters the newline character, which it then reads and discards.

Alternatively, because it looks like you just want a word, why not just use the method that reads one word?

```
std::cin >> input;
```